# How do I print multiple ioComp Plotx plots to a Nova PDF 'printer'?

Tags: vb6, activex

I am trying to print the images from the ioComp iPlotX object to a PDF printer.   This object has iPlotX.SaveToBitmap, which does work and I can 'send' the file to the PDF printer, but the image is blurry, the bitmap is 96 DPI.

The control has iPlotX.PrintChart method which is supposed to go directly to a printer. There is also a method to indicate which Windows printer to direct the output to. I fumbled around to see if I could get anything to work and a couple times I produced an image in the PDF file that was very clear. But other items printed to the page were gone and I only had one page instead of 3 pages. Most of the times nothing is in the PDF file.

A snippet of my relevant code is below.

```
Me.SinglePlotObject1(iIndex).PlotControl.PrintShowDialog = False
Me.SinglePlotObject1(iIndex).PlotControl.Printername = modNovaPDFConstants.NOVAPDF_PRINTER_NAME
Me.SinglePlotObject1(iIndex).PlotControl.PrintOrientation = poLandscape
Me.SinglePlotObject1(iIndex).PlotControl.PrintChart
```

This note is from the ioComp.Help:

> Note : If you have set PrintShowDialog to TRUE and have set
>   PrinterName to a non-empty string, then the printer selected by the
>   user will be ignored!  The PrinterName property will always override
>   the user printer selection, if you are using our printer dialog  If
>   you plan on showing our built-in printer selection dialog to your end
>   user, then you should set the PrinterName property to an empty string
>   for everything to work correctly.

Also from their help is :

> property `PrintXStart` : Double Used to specify the starting x-axis Min
>   value when implementing multi-page printing.
>
> Description: Use PrintXStart to get or set the starting x-axis Min
>   value when implementing multi-page printing. By default, the
>   PrintXStart and PrintXStop are initialized to the Min and Max of the
>   x-axis display on the screen and will only print out one page. You
>   must manipulate the PrintXStart and PrintXStop in the OnBeforePrint or
>   OnBeforePrintPage event to have multiple pages print out during a
>   single print session.

The only example they show is setting the XStart property to 0.  I am not sure if this means multiple pages for the same graph, that is, the graph is stretched out over multiple page or is this has something to with different iPlots on separate pages.  In the past we have always just used the iPlotX.SaveToBitmap to print.  At that time the plots and text were good enough.

If anyone has any experience with ioComp plot controls and printing, I am willing to try any suggestions.

Right now I am trying to create a test application with as little code as possible to test all of their other printer options.

I have tried their FAQ section but could not find anything related to printing using VB6 and the ActiveX controls.  When I sent a message to them, a smtp error appeared.

DaveInCaz: Good Idea. I tried a different PDF printer and results are the same.  I tried a method of the control called iPrintToDC, passing in the Printer.hDC. This made some progress. I can print two graphs on two pages, but the graphs are about the size of my thumb.  If I change width's or height's, it only makes things worse, by somehow placing the bottom of the graph 'above' the title and removing all the contents of the graph itself; it is as if the graph is wrapped around a cylinder and all I see is where the top and bottom meet.  When I used the .PrintChart method, only the last of two charts would be printed and nothing else I printed would appear.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested with another printer? Just to be sure that the printer itself is not a factor...